# Find the average of all of the degrees in a graph containing $8$ vertices and $21$ edges.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

By the handshaking lemma(?), the sum of all degrees is $42.$ The maximum degree of a graph with $8$ vertices is $7.$ So I guess the answer to be $\frac{7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 2 + 1}{8} = 5.25$. The justification for the numerator is that every graph must contain even number of odd vertices. In this case, there are $6$ odd vertices whose degrees are $7, 7, 7, 7,5, 1.$ I just added $6 \text { and }2$ to complete the sum to $42.$ Does it make sense or am I misunderstanding something?

edit:

I see this question doesn't make sense without the second part. Anyway, this question lifted word for word from my book:

> Suppose that a graph contains eight vertices and $21$ edges.
>
> (a) Find the average of all of the degrees in this graph.
>
> (b) Explain how you know that this graph must contain at least one vertex that has degree less than or equal to $5$ and at least one vertex that has degree greater than or equal to $6$.

Comment: There's not need to assign values to each degree. We know that the sum of degrees is twice the number of edges, hence you just divide that number by the number of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average degree is $\frac{1}{8}$ times the sum $S$ of the degrees of the vertices.
Since every edge joins exactly two vertices, $S=2E=42$ and the average degree is $\frac{21}{4}$.
There is no need to consider the maximum degree of a vertex or perform case-checking, also for the second part: given that the average degree is between $5$ and $6$, there must be at least one vertex with degree $\geq 6$ and at least one vertex with degree $\leq 5$. Otherwise, the average degree would be $\leq 5$ or $\geq 6$.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my OP. Does my answer still make sense?

Comment: @user460345: I updated my answer as well.